# Where can I find a step-by-step guide on how to install Windows 10 AFTER Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, elementary

I previously used Windows 8, then upgraded to 10. Now, after using elementaryOS for a while and being quite satisfied with it, I was thinking about reinstalling Windows 10 in dual-boot, just to play some games every once in a while.

Now, I know that installing Ubuntu and derivatives AFTER Windows is a piece of cake (I have done it myself in the past), while the other way around is a bit of a mess.

Nonetheless, I'd rather try. Since I'm a bit of a noob, I need a simple, step-by-step guide on how to do install Windows 10 in dual boot (so far, I haven't found any).

Thanks in advance.

Oh, and, before someone asks, I'm currently downloading Windows 10 ISO; according to MS's FAQ, it should recognize my hardware (since I registered after upgrading from Windows 8), so the license shouldn't be an issue.

EDIT - a couple more questions:

1) what's the best way to put the Windows ISO on a USB disk? For Linux Live USB I've always used UNetBootin, but I'm guessing it's not going to be of any use in my case.

2) Here are my partitions:

[image: Just a screenshot]

Should I just increase the size of the unallocated space? Or create a new partition?

EDIT 2 - also, I just noticed that gparted doesn't show any swap partition... is that normal?

Comment: That guide is about Windows 7; I am afraid it's not going to be as easy on Windows 10

Comment: Why are you afraid it won't be as easy on Windows 10?

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft have the habit of making things as hard as possible for those who want to use other OSs? If I recall correctly, they added a bunch of s**t in Windows 8 that gave me a few headaches when I installed Ubuntu in dual-boot with it on a friend's PC.

Comment: Those problems were with systems that had UEFI, and Windows installed *first*, by the OEM - the very case you described as a piece of cake. :D Once you have got Linux installed, those problems have already been faced.

Comment: 1: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu or  http://askubuntu.com/questions/59551/how-to-burn-a-windows-iso-to-a-usb-device

Comment: Edit 2: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't Microsoft have the habit of making things as hard as possible for those who want to use other OSs? If I recall correctly, they added a bunch of s**t in Windows 8 that gave me a few headaches when I installed Ubuntu in dual-boot with it on a friend's PC.

It's rather the other way around "dual-boot" was terrible hackery. Once UEFI was adopted and implemented properly by Linux distributions installing OSes along each other was easy, unless you bought hardware from manufacturers that implemented unnecessary limitations. UEFI is a step forwards and Microsoft is supporting 3rd party OSes to their best efforts on Windows certified x86 platforms (that is what you actually buy, a piece of hardware some manufacturer designed according to Microsoft's requirements, Linux is just compatible to this platform, like many others that may be inferior in design, locked or crippled in performance like Chromebooks).

Former Microsoft CEOs may have said stupid things but don't let statements from past times cloud your judgment, we're not in the 1990's anymore, Microsoft hires new talent and anti-FLOSS agenda may have already been unpopular in the company during the last years where Ballmer was still CEO.

So check that you are booting UEFI and everything will be easy: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/40581)

In case you still have to boot MBR, then muru is right: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317)

You can setup a [EFI system partition](https://askubuntu.com/q/559007/40581) and probably tar-backup an existing MBR partitioned installation then restore it to a GPT partition table to utilize all space on big drives and add as many partitions for different operating systems as you like once you figured out how the parts come together. I repeat UEFI is a step forwards.

> 2) Here are my partitions:
>
> [image: Just a screenshot]
>
> Should I just increase the size of the unallocated space? Or create a new partition?

You're really asking a question about Elementary on a Ubuntu-only site. **You're on the wrong site. Please migrate/transfer your question to the correct SE site.** Everyone who claims that Ubuntu sites or any other not-directly to the project related site is a proper support channel for Elementary users is deliberately misguiding users or too lazy to properly answer questions. Stop listening to these people.

That being said check the [type of your partition table](https://askubuntu.com/q/509006/40581) (you probably have a working UEFI setup), be careful and read up how to properly resize LVM.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that, since elementaryOS is based on Ubuntu, this would still have been the right place to ask.

Comment: @random_human_being_ I'm aware of that and I try to be as nice and helpful as possible. Related communities here on SE: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy if you have an Ubuntu (or elementaryOS or whatever) Live media (CD/DVD/USB). The big trouble of installing Windows after your Linux system is that Windows' bootloader will overwrite GRUB. Install Windows and boot from your Live media. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

Replacing `X` with your disk letter (if you have only one disk, which is probably true, the letter will be `a`) and `Y` with your Linux OS' partition number.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX --root-partition=/mnt
```

Again, replacing X with the letter.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
exit
```

Now reboot and GRUB should be back as the default bootloader. Done!

Comment: So for me 'x' would be 'a' and 'y' would be '3', right?