# Problems with USB on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, 16.04, format

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from a bootable USB. I made the disk by opening the iso with Archive Manager and then writing it to USB. I don't know what happened but I cannot format the pen drive now. Here is a screen shot of the error I get:

[image]

Windows shows that the pen drive has 2 MB of space whereas the actual space is > 6 GB. Also, all files in the pen drive are read-only and it doesn't allow me to change permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete pendrive partition table and make new with [gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509006/how-can-i-check-and-change-the-partition-table-type) or `parted`. If there will be any troubles with it you can destroy actual pendrive partition table with `dd` command. Before this make sure with `lsblk` command which of your drives is your pendrive. Assuming that your pendrive is `/dev/sdc` (can contain partitions  sdc1, sdc2, etc...):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M count=1
```

Be very careful, if you type wrong `of` device you can **erase** your actual hdd/ssd partition table.
After making new partition table it will be necessary to format your usb to desired filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it. Do you have any idea about why the USB was created as read only?

Comment: Was it read only in terminal ? like in nautilus