# Unable to mount USB device after creating "gpt" label with `parted`

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, mount

I am following the instructions to [create a UEFI-only bootable-live USB media](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/), but after the completing the step to [change the partition type of the USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509006/how-can-i-check-and-change-the-partition-table-type), I am no longer able to mount the USB.

I first formatted my USB device using the Disks utility tool, with format FAT32.

Then, I unmounted my device:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb
```

and then I used this command:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt
```

Once the command completed, I got a message about how I might need to update `/etc/fstab`, but I can't figure out what to put in that file.

I have tried to mount my device where I previously found it (`/media/$USER/`) but I get this error message when I attempt to do so:

```
mount: /media/$USER: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I need to be able to mount the device again so that I can copy the .iso using p7zip.

Here is output from a `parted --list` command:

```
Model: SanDisk Cruzer Glide (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 8004MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created an empty partition table and still need to create a partition itself:

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 0 8 GiB
```

The above creates an 8 GiB partition, so change this to the size you need or just use `gparted`...

*I would not mount this partition in `fstab` as this happens at boot time and this is a removeable drive, so no need to do that!*

Comment: P.S. The answer you're referring to has been edited in the mean time to include not to forget to create a partition, so I'll close this now as a duplicate of the Q&A you were following originally.

Comment: P.P.S. Please don't thank me!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](/questions/ask)!  **;-)**