# Added a new 10TB HDD. Gparted formats only part of it

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, format

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04. I have added a new 10TB HDD to my system. I used GParted to format it, but it only formats 1.2TB, leaving the rest unusable. I want to keep the drive unpartitioned (having just a single partition).

I also named the drive, and the name got changed to using ALL CAPS, i.e. *Name* was changed to *NAME*. I never had this problem with any of my other formatted drives.

Which format should I use? I want to avoid using any formats that support root ownership.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use GPT, since the (old) MBR has a limit of 2 TiB.

Open GParted → *Device* → *Create Partition Table...* → *Advanced* and choose *gpt*, not the default *msdos* (MBR) partitioning.

[image: Create partition table]

[image: Select gpt]

<sub>Screenshots from [How can I check and change the partition table type?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509006/how-can-i-check-and-change-the-partition-table-type)</sub>

If you plan to install Ubuntu, it is suggested that you use the *ext4* format. With *ext4* you can set your own ownership and permissions. With any Windows format the default owner is root, but you can still use it as a non-root user. Unless using Windows, try not to use Windows formats. *FAT32* cannot have any file over 4GB and *NTFS* needs regular maintenance from Windows, `chkdsk`, `defrag`, etc.

If your *ext4* partition ends up owned by root, you can run the following command to change its owner:

```
sudo chown [username]:[username] '[path_to_mounted_partition]'
```

where `[username]` is the username of the user you want to be the owner and `[path_to_mounted_partition]` is the absolute path to the mounted partition for which you want to change the owner.

For example, if your username is `scott` and your partition is mounted under `/media/scott/mynewdrive`, the command you need to run is:

```
sudo chown scott:scott '/media/scott/mynewdrive'
```

<sub>The answer was derived from the comments of [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred) and [Organic Marble](https://askubuntu.com/users/243321/organic-marble).</sub>

Comment: I have used ext4. The drive has been formatted and the issue settled just days after I posted the question, and it has served me well ever since.

Comment: @ScottFrischmann You may mark this answer as the solution by clicking the gray check mark next to the answer!